# Having trouble combining 2 functions

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently a student in high school. Due to the fact that my state is on complete shutdown because of the whole COVID-19 crisis that is going on. I am trying to add 2 functions into a range of cells to further organize myself while trying my best to stay organized doing school from home.

**Function 1:** `=DAYS(E:E,TODAY())` *Count how many days left to complete an assignment.*

**Function 2:** `=IF(E:E=-1, "PAST DUE")` *If the amount of days left equals -1, it will change the cell text to "PAST DUE".*

The only problems I am having is **A: Combining 2 functions, and B: making the IF statement work.** If there is any way you could help me out, then please try. It would mean a whole lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(DAYS(E:E,TODAY())<0, "PAST DUE", DAYS(E:E,TODAY()))
```

If *{days left}* is less than 0, then return "PAST DUE".  Otherwise, return *{days left}*

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I am glad that I am switching over to this community.

Comment: @DeboStreams - make sure to click the check mark to the left to mark the answer as accepted, and welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
=IF(DAYS(E:E,TODAY())<=-1, "PAST DUE", DAYS(E:E,TODAY()))
```

Comment: lemme take a look :)

Comment: ok yes but no... I need it to still display the number of days I have left until the number of days is less than zero

Comment: `=IF(DAYS(E:E,TODAY())<=-1, "PAST DUE", DAYS(E:E,TODAY()))`?

Answer (score 0):

try for array:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(DAYS(E1:E, TODAY())<0, "PAST DUE", DAYS(E1:E, TODAY())))
```